# How to use push notification with a react created with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification, create-react-app

The problem is how to add to the sw.js so that it can speak with the rest of my code.

I need it because each time that a notification arrives I need to do all sorts of changes to the indexeddb.

If needed I'm ready to eject the app.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?